# Delete UITableHeader title when section contains empty row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am implementing a UITableView to populate contact name of the persons. I have implemented pretty much every thing.

I need to delete the section header title of the section whose rows have been deleted by the user and does not contain any other rows. Is there some way to do that. Simply deleting the value from title array when index.item gives me a crash. Any idea on it..

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return sortedUniqueFirstLetters[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.account = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        view.tintColor = UIColor.setColor(Red: 223, Green: 220, Blue: 224, Alpha: 1)
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete{
            ***if indexPath.item == 0{ //Trying to update title array when a section is empty
                sortedUniqueFirstLetters.remove(at: indexPath.section) //Index out of range error here.
            }***
            sections[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.item)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.middle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont know if this is the best solution but what i would do is call reloadtable. This will recall all the delegates for the table and in the function `tableViewtitleForHeaderInSection` i will check if a section doesnt have rows then put an empty header for that section.

Comment: I tried that both the methods but deosn't seem to be right idea as it is called several times although the section is not empty

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section) > 0 {
        return sortedUniqueFirstLetters[section]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use the `heightForHeaderInSction` as well along with your `titleForHEaderInSction` method. Let me know if below code works for you:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
    if numberOfRows == 0 {
        return ""
    }else{
        return sortedUniqueFirstLetters[section]
    }

}

func tableView (tableView:UITableView , heightForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> Float {
    let title = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    if (title == "") {
        return 0.0
    }
    return 80.0
}
```

Comment: Instead of implementing `heightForHeaderInSection` (which really only needs to be used with `viewForHeaderInSection`), simply return `nil` from `titleForHeaderInSection` instead of empty string.

Comment: I am getting a crahs at numberOfRows == 0.